# Indexing numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

So lets say I have a `(4,10)` array initialized to zeros, and I have an input array in the form `[2,7,0,3]`. The input array will modify the zeros matrix to look like this:

```
[[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I know I can do that by looping through the input target and indexing the matrix array with something like `matrix[i][target in input target]`, but I tried to do it without a loop doing something like:
`matrix[:, input_target] = 1`, but that sets me the entire matrix to all 1.
Apparently the way to do it is:
`matrix[range(input_target.shape[0]), input_target]`, the question is why this works and not using the colon ?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example with the colon, you are selecting every row of the columns you specify, while when you provide specific rows, only those are modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only wish to update one column for each row. Therefore, with [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) you must explicitly provide those row identifiers:

```
A = np.zeros((4, 10))
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), [2, 7, 0, 3]] = 1
```

Result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Using a colon for the row indexer will tell NumPy to update *all* rows for the specified columns:

```
A[:, [2, 7, 0, 3]] = 1

array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I think of using the range as a way of telling python to go one row at a time with the correspondent value in the input_array ([2, 7, 0, 3]). I think is now clear to me with your example. Thanks!